# Load low resolution image and progressive load of high resolution

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

How do I display a low resolution image on a page and then after a second delay load a high resolution version? Is this done with layers? Threads?

Comment: We need more information. Are you talking about vanilla Objective-C application? Or a HTML page? Do you have control over the image data on the server?

Comment: cocoa-touch - ipad/iphone application

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old, but just in case someone is looking for it, there is a project called [NYXImagesKit](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit) that does what you are looking for.

It has a class named `NYXProgressiveImageView` that is a subclass of `UIImageView`.

All you have to do is:

```
NYXProgressiveImageView * imgv = [[NYXProgressiveImageView alloc] init];
imgv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[imgv loadImageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourimage"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgv];
[imgv release];
```

Also, a good option is to save your images as `interlaced` so that it loads with low quality and improve with the download. If the image is normal it is loaded from top to bottom.

Comment: do you know any other class that do the same? this class only support iOS 5 +.. i need it works in iOS 4.3 +

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

1) Save the images on the server in a format that supports progressive download ([progressive JPEG](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-11.html), [interlaced PNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngpic2.html)). I think you’d have to come up with a special support on the client, ie. write the image decoding part from PNG/JPEG to `UIImage` yourself, presumably using some library.

2) Save a small thumbnail along each image on the server. When you want to download an image, you’d first download the thumbnail, do a simple scaling to stretch it to the full image size and in the meantime download the full version. There can be multiple thumbnails in various sizes if you really want to get fancy. You’ll have more data on the server, but the client code should be fairly straightforward.

3) Maybe you already have the thumbnails on the client? In that case you can stretch the thumbnail to the full image size to create a low-resolution version while you load the rest.

And if you are asking about how to exactly code the second or third solution… You don’t really need explicit threads and I’m not sure what does “layer” mean in this context. Loading an `UIImage` from network is pretty easy, a bit like this:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewhere/foo.png"];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
    returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

You can turn this code into a function, load and display the thumbnail and then load and display the full image. All this could be done [in background](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground:withObject:) so that you can do something while the data is loading.

Comment: Loading a syncrhonous request on the main thread stalls it (which is a bad user experience) and loading an `UIImage` on the main thread is unsafe (like all other `UI*` classes), so as-written this code shouldn't be recommended. Using the asynchronous `NSURLConnection` from the main thread is okay though.

Comment: Loading a synchronous request blocks the current thread, but as I wrote, you can run the whole code in background. That way you won’t block the main thread and still can use the simple synchronous interface to `NSURLConnection` instead of the clumsy callbacks. Loading an `UIImage` in background thread is safe, I use such code myself.

Answer (score 1):

In general this feature is achieved with image files saved in some [interlaced/progessive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlace_%28bitmaps%29) mode. This allows the displaying application (i.e. browser) to display the image successively starting in a low quality as the first chunks of data arrive. The more of the data is available, the higher the quality of the image gets.

This feature is independent of the web server. Only the client application is responsible of supporting this mode

[This site](http://loriweb.pair.com/interex.html) shows some examples.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you a describing something like the TTPhotoViewController from Three20 (used in the Facebook iPhone app).  When you first start looking at an image it's simply a thumbnail that has been stretched out.  The "high res" version is being downloaded in the background, and when that download is complete it replaces the existing stretched image.

Comment: In this case it is done with Threads.  Most commonly done is to load the thumbnail, spin off a thread to start downloading the larger image, and then run a
    self performSelectorOnMainThread:
Since you need to be in the main thread to meddle with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download with afnetworking.I used the below code

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath =  [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempPath"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourUrl"]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    self.actualImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]]];
    self.actualImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

}];

[operation start];
```