# Algorithm for packing images in increments of quality

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing

I wish to pack an image as a low-quality image along with packets of "quality increments", such that patching the low-quality image with the "quality increments" increases its quality and brings it closer to the original image.

To put it more clearly,

I want to pack an image as a "base-image" (original image in poor quality, say 10%), and packets q1, q2, q3, .... qn

such that

```
base-image + q1 = original image at quality 20%

base-image + q1 + q2 = original image at quality 30% 

...

base-image + q1 +q2 + .... qn = original image at quality 100%
```

My requirement is to pack an image and send it via a Single Board Computer (Raspberry Pi). I need to reduce the file size as much as possible, but the image should not be pixelized so much that it is unclear. Using this "Image quality in increments" approach, my idea is to get an image of low quality, and receive only a few increments (say till q3) and deem it "acceptable" so I can stop sending/receiving any more data packets.

Please guide me on how to approach this.

Comment: Generally, the efficient way to reduce the file size is to apply an image compression algorithm. Is it the way you are considering ?

Comment: Standard as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691649/load-low-resolution-image-and-progressive-load-of-high-resolution . You load the image with ever increasing resolution, and may abort after a fixed set time when the resolution/quality is high enough. Hooking in the image loading is documented somewhat too. A challenge.

Comment: @Damien Yes. I wanted to imply "lossy image compression" when I mentioned "reducing quality". Sorry if I didn't word it out properly

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of the image, and do you have a sample image? I presume it is the receiver who decides when quality is sufficient? I presume you have 2-way communication between sender and receiver? What sort of latency is there in communicating and how often is the sender likely to transmit?

Comment: @MarkSetchell image size is 720x576. Yes, we have two-way communication but the catch is that every communication has a very strict limit of stream size while communication. Once in 15 minutes, we are able to receive only a single packet. Our requirement is to have an 'acceptable-quality' image in the minimum amounts of data transfer

Comment: What is the limit on packet size please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Packet size is limited to be under 1 kB

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy I think JPEG2000 format supports what you are looking for.

Comment: An issue with using increasingly high-res images is that we're getting a lot of redundant data (basically all previous data is useless once we've complete a new image). I think a closer solution to what OP wants would be to use Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) for image compression. It has a stacking behavior behind its compression scheme that allows you to add new data to previous data to get a better image.  Here's a good source for the concept: (http://www.math.utah.edu/~goller/F15_M2270/BradyMathews_SVDImage.pdf). Read at least Section 1's key point and see page 9 for an example image.

Comment: Do you have a representative sample image please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not allowed to share a sample image.

Comment: Ok. Is it colour or greyscale please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is a color image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick toy example of what I mentioned in the comments

Original:

[image]

Rebuilt at 0.2 compression

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
height, width = img.shape[:2];
max_rank = min([width, height]);

# do svd
columns, diags, rows = np.linalg.svd(img, full_matrices = False);

# rebuild image with reduced rank
rank = int(max_rank * 0.2);
rebuilt = np.dot(columns[:,:rank] * diags[:rank], rows[:rank, :]);
rebuilt = rebuilt.astype(np.uint8)

# show image
cv2.imshow("Image", img);
cv2.imshow("Rebuilt", rebuilt);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

The idea here is that you can send each column, diagonal, and row one at a time. The number of full sets you have whenever you decide to stop waiting is the rank that you'll use to reconstruct the image.

A more complete example

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# receiver
client = [[], [], []]; # columns, diags, rows
def receive(column, value, row):
    # grab global
    global client;

    # add new data
    client[0].append(column);
    client[1].append(value);
    client[2].append(row);

# load image
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
height, width = img.shape[:2];
max_rank = min([width, height]);

# do svd
columns, diags, rows = np.linalg.svd(img, full_matrices = False);

# "send" data to client one rank at a time
for a in range(max_rank):
    # check progress
    print("Total Ranks Sent: " + str(a + 1));

    # get a single rank
    column = columns[:,a];
    value = diags[a];
    row = rows[a,:];

    # "send" to client
    receive(column, value, row);

    # rebuild image with current client side data
    client_cols, client_diags, client_rows = client;

    # convert to numpy
    client_cols = np.array(client_cols);
    client_diags = np.array(client_diags);
    client_rows = np.array(client_rows);
    client_cols = np.transpose(client_cols);

    # rebuild
    rebuilt = np.dot(client_cols * client_diags, client_rows);
    rebuilt = rebuilt.astype(np.uint8);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Rebuilt", rebuilt);
    key = cv2.waitKey(0);

    # early quit
    if key == ord('q'):
        break;
```

Comment: Very interesting. I tried your second piece of code and it seems to me that sending each rank of your image entails transmission of around 9k bytes (3600 for `col`, 8 for `value` and 5400 for `row`). Is that correct? I could only guess it was a sunflower at 4 ranks, which is 36kB *in toto*. A JPEG at quality 5 is 5kB and seems somehow *"better"* and a JPEG at quality 10 is about 11kB and even better. Or am I not comparing like with like?

Comment: Lol, you're right. I didn't even think about how big a stack of floating points can get. This is definitely a naive implementation. I'm not an information theory expert; nothing I code up from scratch is going to even come close to well-established compression algorithms. You'll have to look around to find a real implementation of the idea.